# how to check which directory is occupying more space on a unix machine?

Tags: unix

I have multiple folders inside /local/mnt/workspace on my unix machine. How to know which folder is occupying more space? Is there a command?

```
/local/mnt/workspace
```

Comment: You can use `du -k .` to get a summary of all directories below this one. `-k` means "express result in kB".

Comment: `du /local/mnt/workspace | sort -n` should make it. Last one will be the biggest.

Comment: Suggest using -k flag to get result in kB rather than "blocks". More intuitive.

Comment: @Floris - i only want to size of top-level directories under /local/mnt/work/space .."du -k ." seems to point size for every subdirectory ,how to get size of only top-level directory?

Comment: @python.beginner - see my detailed answer. Use the `-d1` flag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the command `du`.

```
du /local/mnt/workspace
```

To get size only for top-level directories:

```
du -k --max-depth=1 /local/mnt/workspace
```

To print the result in GB,

```
du -B1073741824 --max-depth=1 /local/mnt/workspace
```

Comment: i only want to size of top-level directories under /local/mnt/work/space .."du -k ." seems to point size for every subdirectory ,how to get size of only top-level directory?

Comment: @timrauu - thanks,is there a way to get the output printed in GB?

Comment: @python.beginner you should check `man df`, all this info is there.

Comment: @python.beginner updated again.

Comment: @fedorqui you meant to say "check `man du`" . `df` is used to see how full a disk (volume) is.

Comment: @Floris errr... yes, lapsus linguae.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the various comments and permutations - the basic command you are looking for is `du` (which stands for "disk usage"). You can use this with various options.

In its most basic form,

```
du directoryName
```

will give you a listing (in blocks) of all the directories below this one, and their size. For example, on my machine

```
du /etc
```

results in (first few lines only)

```
16  ./apache2/extra
16  ./apache2/original/extra
32  ./apache2/original
0   ./apache2/other
8   ./apache2/users
176 ./apache2
```

Note that it lists directories by depth, and then summarizes as it goes up a level (thus you see `original/extra` and then `original` which includes the size of `extra`.)

Some helpful flags:

```
-k    express result in kB rather than "blocks" (which can depend on your file system)

-s    summarize result (don't give individual directories; just the final number)

-d    go only to a certain depth (handy to see the result of directories "at your level" 
      without worrying about what goes on deeper down)
```

For your purpose, a good command might be

```
du -k -d1 /local/mnt/workspace | sort -rn | head -5
```

This will get you the top five directories (in terms of space used) at the level of `workspace`. It will display your use in kB. Obviously you can change the parameter of `head` to change the number of files you want to see.

With a tip of the hat to @fedorqui who suggested, in a comment, the use of `sort`.